# How can i make bootstrap grid system to work with modal sizes

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I am including a template inside a modal which is being used elsewhere as well ::

```
<div id="addressModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div ng-include="'templates/add-address.html'"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

i dont want to modify the grid system inside this template only for this modal window , as it is being used in other places as well . So my question is that there are coloumns in this template with :

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6>'my content'</div>
```

since my modal window is small, u can consider it in 'sm' range, but nevertheless it positions its layout according to 'md' only . Is there any tweak to have the modals accept grid sizes according to the modal window size ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is not about how small is your modal window, but about screen width.
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp
You can see in the bottom of this page the width in pixels for each .col class.

So, you must think it as screen resolution, when you use the .col classes to be activated. This, or you can create your own classes with width estimated in % and use media to proper display them.